# How long will StreetPass parties stay on my map?

Tags: fire-emblem-awakening, streetpass

I've StreetPassed with a few other *Fire Emblem Awakenings* players, I can shop or battle their parties on my map.  I need to earn more money to buy some high level items for sale by one StreetPass party.  How long will the StreetPass parties stay on my map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sortie party met via StreetPass will stay on the map indefinitely until you Parley with them and either Fight or Shop.  However, they will be defeated and leave if a Risen battle appears on their spot and you don't immediately help them out with that Risen battle.

Comment: This is not true. If a risen generates on their spot, your party will team up with them to fight the risen, after which you can challenge the street pass

Comment: @KevinDuke - I've tried to clarify what I was saying a bit. You and the StreetPass team can team up against the Risen, but it's not automatic - you have to go to that spot.